# Extension of differentiable structure to guarantee continuous extension of prescribed vector fields

Tags: differential-topology, extension

Consider the lower half space $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \; | \; y < 0\}$ and let $X_1, X_2$ be two vector fields on the lower half space which are continuous with respect to its canonical differentiable structure but which do not extend as continuous vector fields to **all of** $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to the canonical differentiable structure on **all of** $\mathbb{R}^2$.

My question is what is known about conditions (or obstructions to) under which I can extend the differentiable structure on the lower half space to a differentiable structure on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is compatible with the continuous structure of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and in which the vector fields $X_1, X_2$ extend continuously.